# What is missing reference exception in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity 3d and I have missing reference exception.The error
don't appear in my script editor so I don't know what is this error related to.
Here is the Gamemanager  script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Gamemanager : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<Character> Characters = new List<Character>();
public List <Item> AllItems = new List<Item> ();
bool ShowCharWheel;
public int SelectedCharacter;
int LastCharacter;
public static Gamemanager Instance;
public bool CanShowSwitch = true;
public Character CurrentCharacter; 

void Awake()
{
    foreach (Character c in Characters)
    {
        c.Instance = Instantiate(c.PlayerPrefab, c.HomeSpawn.position, c.HomeSpawn.rotation) as GameObject;
        c.Instance.GetComponent<PlayerController> ().LocalCharacter = c;
    }
    ChangeCharacterStart(Characters[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedChar")]);
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}
void ChangeCharacterStart(Character c)
{

    LastCharacter = SelectedCharacter;
    SelectedCharacter = Characters.IndexOf(c);
    CurrentCharacter = c;
    Characters [LastCharacter].Instance.GetComponent<PlayerController> ().CanPlay = false;
    Characters[SelectedCharacter].Instance.GetComponent<PlayerController>().CanPlay = true;
    Camera.main.GetComponent<SmoothFollow>().target = Characters[SelectedCharacter].Instance.transform;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SelectedChar", SelectedCharacter);
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (CanShowSwitch) {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.C)) {
            ShowCharWheel = true;

        } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.V)) {
            ShowCharWheel = false;

        }

    }
}

void ChangeCharacter(Character c)
{
    c.Instance.GetComponent<AI> ().DoneHome = false;
    if (Vector3.Distance (Characters [SelectedCharacter].Instance.transform.position, c.Instance.transform.position) > 10) {
        sequencemanager.Instance.StartCoroutine ("DoCharSwitch", c);
        CanShowSwitch = false;
        LastCharacter = SelectedCharacter;
        SelectedCharacter = Characters.IndexOf (c);
        CurrentCharacter = c;
        Characters [LastCharacter].Instance.GetComponent<PlayerController> ().CanPlay = false;
        Characters [SelectedCharacter].Instance.GetComponent<PlayerController> ().CanPlay = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("SelectedChar", SelectedCharacter);

    } else {
        LastCharacter = SelectedCharacter;
        SelectedCharacter = Characters.IndexOf(c);
        CurrentCharacter = c;
        Characters [LastCharacter].Instance.GetComponent<PlayerController> ().CanPlay = false;
        Characters [SelectedCharacter].Instance.GetComponent<PlayerController> ().CanPlay = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("SelectedChar", SelectedCharacter);
        Camera.main.GetComponent<SmoothFollow> ().target = Characters [SelectedCharacter].Instance.transform;

    }


}


void OnGUI()
{
    if (ShowCharWheel)
    {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(Screen.width - 64, Screen.height - 256, 64, 208), GUIContent.none, "box");
        foreach (Character c in Characters)
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button(c.Icon, GUILayout.Width(64), GUILayout.Height(64)))
            {
                ChangeCharacterStart(c);
            }
        }
    GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
}
    }

  [System.Serializable]
  public class Character
  {
public string Name;
public Texture2D Icon;
public GameObject PlayerPrefab;
public GameObject Instance;
public Transform HomeSpawn;
   }

[System.Serializable]
 public class Item
{
public string Name;
public Texture2D Icon;
public ItemInstance InstancePrefab;
 }
```

The error is on line

```
c.Instance = Instantiate(c.PlayerPrefab, c.HomeSpawn.position, c.HomeSpawn.rotation) as GameObject;
```

[image] 
This is my editor image with error.The main problem is when I start the game it destroy the gamemanager script.
And another important thing.I migrated this project.I had to reinstall windows.Before that the error didn't appeared.And now it do.And I am sure I took the whole pro

Comment: It's almost the same as `Null reference exception` but it's called from the Unity. Debug it and check which one is null.

Comment: Debug using the script editor(which I have already done)or debug using unity

Comment: The real debug. I see that you're using Visual Studio so attach this to the Unity editor and start debugging.

Comment: The problem is what the error says. One of the objects you're trying to spawn from has been destroyed, but you still have a reference for it. That reference is now obsolete, causing an error. The destroyed object is *probably* c.HomeSpawn, although it could also be c.PlayerPrefab.

Comment: I am using Monodevelop and can you please tell me how to do the same thing in monodevelop.

Comment: Try breaking up long commands if they are causing bugs. e.g. read the position of c.Homespawn into a Vector3 before using it. That makes it clearer which part of the command is causing the error.

Comment: @JasonLang It remove the whole gamemanager script whenever I start playing.

Comment: @JasonLang  I am a complete newbie and don't have the slightest experience in c#.I was following a tutorial.Please Can you tell me how to read the position of c.Homespawn into a Vector3?

Comment: "Vector3 position =  c.Homespawn.position;" then you use "position" in place of c.Homespawn.position. If the error was in c.Homespawn, then the error will now trigger on this new line instead of the other one. it helps narrow things down.

Comment: Have you populate you Characters list from editor?

Comment: @maximelian1986 Thanks! I solved this problem but now it give the error on line 38 NullRefferenceException

Comment: @JasonLang  I solved this problem but now it give NullRefferenceException  error on line 38.

Comment: remember we don't have the line numbers here :P

Comment: @JasonLang Sorry man this line:"     Camera.main.GetComponent<SmoothFollow>().target = Characters[SelectedCharacter].Instance.transform;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just a junior developer without much of experience but your code looks messy. May be there is more null refs errors so most probably you did not assign/ save to prefab something or an object that you want to use is destroyed. Check [how to debug with monobehaviour] (https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/monodevelops-debugger). So put some break point, and go through them one by one. When break point activated you can hover over variable and check if it has some value. I strongly suggest you make any assignment on separate line like this:

```
c.Instance = Instantiate(c.PlayerPrefab, c.HomeSpawn.position, c.HomeSpawn.rotation) as GameObject;
```

should be like this:

```
GameObject newGameObject = Instantiate(c.PlayerPrefab, c.HomeSpawn.position, c.HomeSpawn.rotation) as GameObject;
c.Instance = newGameObject;
```

In that case you can check if you really have newGameObject and so on.