# Difference between "Missing Reference Exception" and "Null Reference Exception" in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the Unity manual there's an explanation for [Null Reference Exceptions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NullReferenceException.html) but not for Missing Reference Exceptions. Are there any differences?

Comment: [Sounds like it's the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761097/what-is-missing-reference-exception-in-c#comment72638484_42761097), still looking for an official answer.

Comment: So this is great, the only official documentation for MissingReferenceException on Unity's website is [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/MissingReferenceException.html) - a Legacy version with no content :(

Comment: @gunr2171 The documentation could definitely use some updating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NullReferenceException` is thrown when you try to access member of a variable set to null.
`MissingReferenceException` is thrown when you try to access a GameObject that has been destroyed by some logic in your code.

Comment: Some links I've found to back up that info: [one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/missingreferenceexception.17526/), [two](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000404563), [three](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136674/nullreferenceexception-in-unity#comment240378_136674), [four](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/2d-missingreferenceexception-is-thrown-while-saving-a-tile-palette).

Comment: Great, I thought it was something like that. I've found 
`catch (System.NullReferenceException)`
catches both: MissingReference and NullReference

Comment: Note that things that throw `MissingReferenceException` will also evaluate `obj == null` as true. This is because while the object *may not be literally* null, Unity knows that the object has been marked for deletion and is *functionally the same as* null (it just hasn't been removed from memory yet).